# Codes does not work anymore after converting embedded macros to vba in ms access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have converted an embedded macro to VBA in ms access 2010 and does not work at all. To give a conrete example. I made an **Add Record** button using the wizard and works perfectly but upon converting it into VBA by using the built in feature **Convert Form's Macros to Visual Basic** and the button won't do anything anymore. I actually don't know what I'm doing wrong as I am a newby in MS Access 2010. But i used to do this in MS Access 2007 and it's flawless.

Can somebody give me an idea what's im doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**This is what the MS Access 2010 generated code after converting Macros to VBA**

```
Private Sub cmd_AddRecord_Click()
    On Error GoTo cmd_AddRecord_Click_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If

    cmd_AddRecord_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

    cmd_AddRecord_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmd_AddRecord_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Show some code, please. Also, have you tried not converting anything? Office 2010 is backwards compatible for the most part (from what I got so far).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The button literally won't do anything after converting it vba for some reason. But if you view code, code is there.

Comment: Hi bernard, I just tried what you ask regarding macro and a converted to vba. The button converted to macros doesnt work and the one on macro works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the button "OnClick" property is set to `[Event Procedure]`. This is probably your problem.

Also, this code is really complicated in its auto generated state. Try this:

```
Private Sub cmd_AddRecord_Click()
    On Error GoTo cmd_AddRecord_Click_Err

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec


    Exit Sub

    cmd_AddRecord_Click_Err:
        Beep
        MsgBox err.Description, vbOKOnly, ""

End Sub
```